# how do you limit the number of ngrep results?

Tags: ngrep

There appears to be no way to do this from the man page. When I run `ngrep` on a port that's serving continuous traffic, I get a ton of results streaming. I want to limit to the number of results such a what can be done with `grep -m`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `ngrep -n` which only matches "x" total packets, where x is your input.